# Problems with pi_list_browseresults()

Tags: typo3

I am building an extension in typo3 where I am using pi_list_browseresults().

My sql query is:

```
  *$query='SELECT * FROM tx_jobs_messages 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tx_jobs_messages_user_mm ON tx_jobs_messages.uid=tx_jobs_messages_user_mm.uid_local  
   WHERE  tx_jobs_messages_user_mm.uid_foreign ='. intval($feUserId) .'';*
```

I have no idea to execute above query using **"pi_exec_query"**.

I gave a code as shown below. But it is displaying 0 results

```
  $res= $this->pi_exec_query('',1,'','','','',$query);

  list($this->internal['res_count']) = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_row($res);

  // Make listing query, pass query to SQL database: 

  $res=$this->pi_exec_query('',0,'','','','',$query);

  $this->internal['currentTable'] = 'tx_jobs_messages';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below syntax for pi_exec_query:

```
pi_exec_query ($table, $count=0, $addWhere='', $mm_cat='', $groupBy='', $orderBy='', $query='');
```

Reference link: http://doxygen.frozenkiwi.com/typo3/html/df/d32/classtslib__pibase.html#a014ebbab057051507a8c92ecd919ed3e